# Excel Apache POI - Shape with Text inside

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a shape with a textString inside of it. I have been able to center the textBox, however I cannot seem to center align the center.

Using Apache Poi v. 3.9

EX:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 25, 3, 32);
XSSFSimpleShape shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
XSSFRichTextString textString = new XSSFRichTextString();
XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();

font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.ELLIPSE);

textString.setString(LeadSheetCoverPage.ADD_YOUR_LOGO.getText(dataStore.getLanguage()));
textString.applyFont(font);

shape.getCTShape().getTxBody().getBodyPr().setAnchor(STTextAnchoringType.CTR);
// This line below doesn't seem to align the Paragraph text to center 
shape.getCTShape().getTxBody().getPList().get(0).getPPr().setAlgn(STTextAlignType.CTR);

shape.setFillColor(211, 211, 211);
shape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
shape.setText(textString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the current `apache poi 4.1.0` the `XSSFSimpleShape` provides [XSSFSimpleShape.setVerticalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSimpleShape.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment-). And the text is in `XSSFTextParagraph`s which provide [XSSFTextParagraph.setTextAlign](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTextParagraph.html#setTextAlign-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.TextAlign-).

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreateExcelShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 25, 3, 32);
   XSSFSimpleShape shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);

   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.ELLIPSE);
   shape.setFillColor(211, 211, 211);
   shape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
   shape.setText("The text inside the shape.");

   shape.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
   shape.getTextParagraphs().get(0).setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Not apache 3.9, also I have tried this, it doesn't center align the text.
   shape.getTextParagraphs().get(0).setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was neither of the above, and I did not want to upgrade.

```
CTTextParagraphProperties lv1PPr = 
        shape.getCTShape().getTxBody().getLstStyle().addNewLvl1PPr();
lv1PPr.setAlgn(STTextAlignType.CTR);
```

For some reason the above methods wouldn't work, but it worked on the STTextAnchoringType.